# Change Nimbus Font family to Times Roman

Tags: pdftex, times

My code follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{linguex}%
\usepackage{tikz}%
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,calc,arrows.meta}%
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\ex.
\Tree [.CauseP [.DP \edge[roof]; {`the zog'} ] [ [.\textsc{cause} ] [
[.\textsc{past} ] [.vP \edge[roof]; {`dissolved the
house'} ]]] ]

\end{document}
```

I am running this through `PDFLaTeX`, and the font name shows as `Nimbus`, refer the below screenshot:

[image]

But I expect Font name should show as Times, eventhough I am using PDFLaTeX, is this possible, please advise...

Comment: Nimbus is a times clone.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, I too said the same to one of my friend, but he expects the name Times as the font name not Nimbus, also he wants to do work with PDFLaTeX only...

Comment: @MadyYuvi - Please inform your friend that he/she needs to get use to the notion of font clones looking identical to the original (except, maybe, to some real font freaks...). As long as Nimbus is indistinguishable from Times, why would your friend even care?

Comment: There is a winfonts package which uses the times.ttf from windows, but it is broken. So your friend should better get type1-version of times (it will not be easy to find and will perhaps cost money) and someone who sets them up for pdflatex (will probably cost money too).

Comment: @Mico - Why would the friend care? One unlikely possibility: Some commercial printers refuse fonts not on a "known licensed list," for legal reasons. It may be that anything using the word "Times" is considered to be licensed, but "Nimbus" is unknown. Also, in the world of E-books, many distributors automatically remove any font specification or embedding, again for legal reasons, An in-house substitute is performed, depending on the generic category of serif or sans-serif. The equivalent for "Times" is known, but probably not known for "Nimbus."